# BAPI_PERSDATA_CHANGE to update user data using SAP JCo 3

Tags: java, jco, bapi, sap-hr

I'm using the following code snippet. The goal is to update the user lastname firstname and co using the BAPI_PERSDATA_CHANGE bapi. But somehow it's not working, I tried a lot of possibilities but it's not working. The message to the function related to BAPI_PERSDATA_CHANGE is:

```
No data stored for 0002 in the selected period
```

I'm using the following code

```
public boolean writeData(long id, HashMap<String, String>  userData) throws Exception{
    String DST1 = "ABAP_AS";
    JCoDestination dest = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(DST1);
    JCoFunctionTemplate template = dest.getRepository().getFunctionTemplate("BAPI_PERSDATA_CHANGE");
    JCoFunction jcoFunction = template.getFunction();
    jcoFunction.getImportParameterList().setValue("EMPLOYEENUMBER", id);
    //jcoFunction.getImportParameterList().setValue("SUBTYPE", "002");
    //jcoFunction.getImportParameterList().setValue("OBJECTID", "");
    //jcoFunction.getImportParameterList().setValue("LOCKINDICATOR", "");
    jcoFunction.getImportParameterList().setValue("VALIDITYBEGIN", "19570101"); //"1994-04-24");
    jcoFunction.getImportParameterList().setValue("VALIDITYEND", "99991231");
    jcoFunction.getImportParameterList().setValue("RECORDNUMBER", "000");
    jcoFunction.getImportParameterList().setValue("FIRSTNAME", "FOfie modifier");
    JCoFunction jCoFunction1 = dest.getRepository().getFunctionTemplate("BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT").getFunction();
    JCoFunction BAPI_EMPLOYEE_DEQUEUE = dest.getRepository().getFunction("BAPI_EMPLOYEE_DEQUEUE");
    BAPI_EMPLOYEE_DEQUEUE.getImportParameterList().setValue("NUMBER", id);
    jcoFunction.execute(dest);
    jCoFunction1.execute(dest);
    BAPI_EMPLOYEE_DEQUEUE.execute(dest);
    JCoContext.end(dest);
    return false;
}
```

Am I missing something ? Or doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly described in the error message.

```
No data stored for 0002 in the selected period
```

means that there is no data for the infotype `0002` for the period given in the parameters `VALIDITYBEGIN` and `VALIDITYEND` hence there is nothing to be updated.

Ensure that the data for the aforementioned infotype is provided for the `EMPLOYEENUMBER` in the requested period of time.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
JCoContext.begin(dest);
```

is missing. Therefore the execution of BAPI_PERSDATA_CHANGE and of BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT will happen in two different ABAP sessions...